# Getting a vehicle as a temporary resident in New South Wales, Australia

Tags: australia, motorcycles, new-south-wales

I've been living in Sydney for about half a year now, with 1 more year on my visa (and hopefully a sponsorship to follow).

I'm interested in getting a motorbike to allow me to explore the area better. Trains just don't cut it.

I have a Polish driver's license for cars and motorbikes and an international driver's permit with the same categories. Am I allowed to buy and ride here without any extra licensing?

I've found this question: [Buying a car in Australia or New Zealand as a non-resident?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67766/buying-a-car-in-australia-or-new-zealand-as-a-non-resident) but the answers seem to focus on New Zealand.

Comment: Should this question be on expats rather than travel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues here: licensing (whether you can ride) and registration (whether you can transfer a vehicle to your name).

You can use your overseas driver's licence to drive in New South Wales as long as you are a [temporary visitor](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/licence/visiting-nsw.html#ApplyingforaNSWlicenceasatemporaryoverseasvisitor).  If you wish, you can obtain a [NSW temporary visitor licence](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/licence/visiting-nsw.html#ApplyingforaNSWlicenceasatemporaryoverseasvisitor).

If you stop being a temporary visitor (e.g. if you get a permanent visa), then you have [3 months to obtain a local driver's licence](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/licence/moving-to-nsw.html#Internationaldriversandriders).

As a Polish licence holder, you can obtain a NSW driver's licence without needing to pass the knowledge and driving tests if you are over 25 years of age.

Anyone over 16 years of age can [register a vehicle](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/registration/get-nsw-registration/index.html#Whocanregisteravehicle?).  However, it is useful to have a NSW driver's licence as it will make the process easier (e.g. you will be able to transfer the registration online).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a follow up question, how long should I expect it to take to obtain a temporary visitor licence? Given that I might have to leave Australia within 11 months I'd rather waste a bit of time and effort registering offline rather than waste considerably more time waiting for a licence. Maybe it's a quick process - it's just that coming from Poland I've learnt to expect the worst when it comes to governmental offices ;)

Comment: See the "What you need to do" section [here](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/licence/moving-to-nsw.html#Internationaldriversandriders).  Assuming you are exempted from all the tests and have all your documentation in order, you will need to visit a motor registry or service centre, who should either issue the licence straight away or have it posted to you in approximately 2 weeks.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot for your answer. I know it's customary to wait a bit before accepting, but I really thinks this answers my question fully so I'm just gonna accept it now.